# xml schema validation error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Here's is my schema code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
            xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="DBF_text">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="paramId" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:element name="CDBText" type="xs:string"/>                   
                <xs:element name="menuLocation" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="sourceText" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="targetText">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And this is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <DBF_text   xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com Translations.xsd">
    <record>
    <paramId>1</paramId>
    <CDBText>ew</CDBText>
    <menuLocation>er</menuLocation>
    <sourceText>tr</sourceText>
    <targetText>rf</targetText>
     </record>
    <record>
    <paramId>2</paramId>
    <CDBText>ee</CDBText>
    <menuLocation>rr</menuLocation>
    <sourceText>tt</sourceText>
    <targetText>ff</targetText>
</record>
</DBF_text>
```

I keep getting this error when trying to validate the schema:
"cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'record'. One of '{"https://www.w3schools.com":Record}' is expected".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most probably because you wrote 'record' with a lower case r, and the element is named Record in the schema. But you should correct your post because in your schema, there's no `Record` element declared -- I suspect we won't get the same error if we try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @patame that should be an answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I corrected the schema as follows: